# Асинхронное чтение/запись в файл Win32API

Tags: winapi, c#, файлы, асинхронность

Здравствуйте.

Напоролся на следующую проблему. Мне надо считать из файлов в каталоге первые n строк и занести в другой файл, причем сделать это надо с помощью функций `Win32 API (CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile и т.д.)`. Сделать все это синхронно не составило труда, но вот сделать асинхронно (а именно так мне и надо) не выходит. В предпоследний параметр функции `CreateFile (flagsAndAttributes)` передаю файловый атрибут `Overlapped`, при этом функция `ReadFile` сразу начинает возвращать `false`. Как организовать считывание-запись, понять не могу. Помогите, пожалуйста. Пишу, вообще говоря, на C#, но код на C++ тоже поможет. Главное - использование `Win32Api` функций и асинхронная работа.

Comment: А откуда берётся требование пользоваться голым WinAPI?

Comment: Такая, к сожалению, задача

Comment: Можно использовать ReadFileEx и WriteFileEx

Comment: Не-не, подождите. _Кто_ поставил перед вами такую задачу? Какая мотивация?

Асинхронное чтение на C#, допустим, просто как 5 копеек:

    using(var in = File.OpenText(infile))
    using(var out = File.CreateText(outfile))
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        var line = await in.ReadLineAsync(in);
        await out.WriteLineAsync(out);
    }

Comment: Странный вопрос, для того, чтобы помочь человеку, надо обязательно знать, кто поставил перед ним задачу?

Comment: @Expert: Мой текст не вполне по теме вопроса: ТС спрашивает, как сделать на C/WinAPI, а я привожу высокоуровневый пример на C#. Так что мой текст скорее комментарий.

Comment: @VladD, Если вы считаете, что предоставленная вами информация не поможет автору в решении вопроса, вы можете перевести ответ в комментарий. Вам доступны все инструменты редактирования, которые доступны мне.

Comment: Я студент, и использование WinAPI является частью заданий.

Comment: @PsiX_dev, а гуглить 

     асинхронный ввод вывод windows

не пробовали?

По первой же [ссылке](http://www.e-reading.link/chapter.php/141823/479/Hart_-_Sistemnoe_programmirovanie_v_srede_Windows.html) можно прочесть (а можно было и сразу предположить), что для Overlapped I/O (IMHO Ваш случай) нужно ждать, пока не станет доступным соответствующий дескриптор или не наступит заданное событие. Там же (по линкам) можно выйти на структуру OVERLAPPED, в которой есть поле HANDLE hEvent; 

Вот как его использовать -- выясняйте

(сам я просто не пишу в винде, поэтому не знаю, а изучать ее нет причин).

Comment: @PsiX_dev: А, понятно, глупое задание. Тогда вопросы снимаются. Вам придётся написать с нуля разбор файла на строки на голом WinAPI, кстати.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса потому что это учебное задание, которое для автора уже давно не актуально, а желания делать учебные задания у сообщества почему-то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что по умолчанию потоки .NET работают в многопоточном апартаменте, а для вызова функций WinApi нужен однопоточный. Попробуйте пометить методы, которые Вы используете для асинхронного запуска атирбутом `STAThread`, или при создании потока вызывать `SetApartmentState` у потока. Правда, всякая асинхронка работает через `ThreadPool`, которому нужен многопоточный апартамент. Поэтому о синтаксисе `BeginDo - EndDo` для асинхронного вызова функций WinAPI следует забыть.

Comment: Не, не может быть.

Любая библиотечная функция рано или поздно вызовет WinAPI, то есть, если для WinAPI нужно было бы STA, то из MTA вовсе невозможно быьт бы обращаться к файлам.

Comment: Ну, у меня как-то вообще в MTAThread не работал никакой pinvoke. По крайней мере, я бы точно стал копать в эту сторону.